# Can WebBrowser Document Image- border, align, hSpace and vSpace be set?

Tags: delphi, browser

When this code is executed, the `src` and `alt` are set correctly, but `border`, `align`, `hspace` and `vspace` produce `EOleException` - *bad varialble type*.

Is it possible to set `border`, `align`, `hspace` and `vspace` with webbrowser and if so, how?
Is there anyway to find out what the correct variable types are?

```
iDoc := ( WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2 );
iDoc.execCommand( 'InsertImage', False, 0 );
iImageIndex := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Length - 1;
iImageFileName := ExtractFileName( iImageFilePath );
// Change the src path to a relative path 
iSrc := ChangeFilePath( iImageFilePath, '..\Images\' );
iImageTextAlternative := FormInsertImage.AlternateText1.Text;
// Set Src 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).src := iSrc;
// Set a text alternative to the graphic 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).Alt := iImageTextAlternative;
// Set border 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).border := FormInsertImage.Border1.EditValue;
// Set align 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).align := FormInsertImage.Alignment1.EditValue;
// Set hSpace 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).hSpace := FormInsertImage.hSpace1.EditValue;
// Set vSpace 
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.Item( iImageIndex ).vSpace := FormInsertImage.vSpace1.EditValue;
```

**Edit - This works now...**

```
iDocument := ( TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2 );
if Assigned( iDocument ) then
begin
  // Insert the image
  iDocument.execCommand( 'InsertImage', False, 0 );
  while TopicWebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  HTMLElementCollection := ( TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2 ).images;
  iImageIndex := TopicWebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.images.Length - 1;
  HTMLImgElement := ( HTMLElementCollection.Item( iImageIndex, 0 ) as IHTMLImgElement );
  // Set the src, alt, border, align, hspace and vspace             HTMLImgElement.src := ChangeFilePath( FormInsertImage.PictureName1.Text, '..\Images\' );
  // Change the src path to a relative path 
  HTMLImgElement.alt := FormInsertImage.AlternateText1.Text;
  HTMLImgElement.border := FormInsertImage.Border1.EditValue;
  HTMLImgElement.align := FormInsertImage.Alignment1.EditValue;
  HTMLImgElement.hspace := FormInsertImage.hspace1.EditValue;
  HTMLImgElement.vspace := FormInsertImage.vspace1.EditValue;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  HTMLImgElement: IHTMLImgElement;
  HTMLElementCollection: IHTMLElementCollection;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.example.com');
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  HTMLElementCollection := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).images;

  for I := 0 to HTMLElementCollection.length - 1 do
  begin
    HTMLImgElement := (HTMLElementCollection.item(I, 0) as IHTMLImgElement);
    HTMLImgElement.src := 'c:\someimage.jpg';
    HTMLImgElement.alt := 'Alternative text ...';
    HTMLImgElement.border := '5';
    HTMLImgElement.align := 'middle';
    HTMLImgElement.hspace := 5;
    HTMLImgElement.vspace := 5;
  end;
end;
```